# Strange bash sytax error depending on sudo usage

Tags: bash, ubuntu, shell-script, root, non-root-user

I made this bash function to detect if the user running is actually logged in as root user and not using sudo by checking the uid + home directory of the user executing the command:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x
function check_root(){
  home=`sh -c 'cd ~/ && pwd'`
  if [ "$home" != "/root" ] || [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    echo -e "This script can only be executed by the root user, not with sudo  elevation"
  exit 1
  fi
}

check_root
```

When i run it as a regular user (uid 1000) it works as expected:

```
++ check_root
+++ sh -c 'cd ~/ && pwd'
++ home=/home/jake
++ '[' /home/jake '!=' /root ']'
++ echo -e 'This script can only be executed by the root user, not with sudo    elevation'
This script can only be executed by the root user, not with sudo elevation
++ exit 1
```

When i run it as root it also works as expected:

```
++ check_root
+++ sh -c 'cd ~/ && pwd'
++ home=/root
++ '[' /root '!=' /root ']'
+++ id -u
++ '[' 0 '!=' 0 ']'
```

But when i run it as regular user (uid 1000) with sudo elevation i get this:

```
./check_root.sh: 4: ./check_root.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

System info:

Linux jake 3.11.0-26-generic #45~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 04:02:35 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

bash --version
GNU bash, versie 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Does the error disappear if you write `function check_root () {` instead? Does it appear if you run it as normal user with `env - ./check_root.sh`?

Comment: The error message indicates that the script is _not_ running under `bash`.  On many systems, for example, `dash` is the default shell and it would give that exact error message.  The details of how you invoke the script would be important here.

Comment: He's running it as `./scriptname` and the shebang is clearly `#!/bin/bash`. I would be puzzled as to why sh would get invoked here.

Comment: Does it help to use standard POSIX shell function syntax instead of the bash extension? Leave out the `function` keyword at the beginning.

Comment: Why are you checking `$home` rather than `$HOME` or, better, the output of `$(whoami)`?

Comment: Exactly what command are you using to run the script with sudo? What is the output of `<check_root.sh head -n 1 | od -t x1`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti: Jake may be copying the `$(cd -P xxxxxx && pwd)` syntax that was suggested in [Bash ... trying to find directory of the script itself](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33882/23408) as a way of getting the target of a symbolic link to a directory.

Comment: @drewbenn, i am trying this in an effort to understand the behaviour of the bash shell on this system. I noticed some discrepancies in the way it calls sudo VS being root, EG the home dir does not become /root if using sudo, what is not expected. I am going to try the suggested commands when i get back to work and check what they do. It just baffled me to get thrown a syntax error in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved this in the mean time but did not yet post the solution - turned out to be syntax-related:

Working solutions:

```
function check_root {
 stuff..
}
```

and

```
function check_root () {
 stuff..
}
```

Eg removing the () from the function declaration or ensuring it is sepaerated by spaces at both sides fixes it.

Here's what i found in the bash manpage that made me spot the mistake :

```
Shell Function Definitions
       A shell function is an object that is called like a simple command and executes a compound command with a new set of positional parameters.  Shell functions are declared as follows:

       name () compound-command [redirection]
       function name [()] compound-command [redirection]
              This defines a function named name.  The reserved word function is optional.  If the function reserved word is supplied, the parentheses are optional
```

But.. i have no clue what exactly makes bash behave this way in this case.